# Errores al compilar usando Ahead of Time

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Me aparece este error cuando intento la compilación ***Ahead of Time*** en un proyecto escrito en angular 2.

> Error: Error at /xxx/app/src/bootstrap.aot.ts:2:36: Cannot find module '../../app-aot/app/src/app.module.ngfactory'.

Este es mi archivo ***bootstrap.aot***:

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types/"
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "app/src/app.module.ts",
      "app/src/bootstrap.aot.ts"
    ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "app-aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

Y esta es mi configuración del bootstrap:

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../../app-aot/app/src/app.module.ngfactory';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

La ruta del `app.module.ngfactory` es correcta, por algún motivo el compilador no me genera los *ngfactories* de la carpeta *app*. Solo veo en la carpeta *app-aot* los relativos a la carpeta *node_modules*, no se qué puedo estar haciendo mal.

¿Alguien se ha encontrado un problema similar?